# Can't Retrieve image from my SQL Server database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I created a table in my database which stores the user's information and his/her picture. My picture column has an `image` data type.

I completed my registration form and successfully added data to my database using this code:

```
 Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click

 comm.CommandText = "insert into Users(user_id, userNo_id, username, password, last_name, middle_name, first_name, course, section, position, address, birthday,picture) values (@field1,@field2,@field3,@field4,@field5, @field6, @field7,@field8, @field9, @field10, @field11,@field12, @photo)"
 comm.Connection = con

 Dim Password As String = String.Empty
 Dim birthday As String
 Dim ms As New MemoryStream

 PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

 Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer

 Dim p As New SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
 p.Value = data
 birthday = cmbMonth.Text + " " + cmbDay.Text + ", " + txtYear.Text

 con.Open()
 Password = Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim())
 With comm
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtUserID.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", txtUserNo_id.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field3", txtUsername.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field4", Password)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field5", txtLastName.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field6", txtMiddleName.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field7", txtFirstName.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field8", txtCourse.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field9", txtSection.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field10", cmbPosition.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field11", txtAddress.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field12", birthday)
     .Parameters.Add(p)

 End With

 comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
 comm.Dispose()
 MsgBox("Records Successfully Saved")
 clear()
 con.Close()
```

But when I tried to retrieve my data especially the picture.. I get an error "Out of Memory"

This is my code trying to retrieve my data and image..

```
 Sub fillDataFields()
    Dim mid As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim first As String

    con.Open()

    comm.CommandText = "Select last_name,middle_name,first_name,course, section, address, " & _
                   "birthday, picture from Users where user_id like @uid"
    comm.Connection = con
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", "%" & frmUsers.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "%")

    dr = comm.ExecuteReader

    While (dr.Read())
        last = (dr("last_name"))
        mid = (dr("middle_name"))
        first = (dr("first_name"))
        txtCourse.Text = (dr("course"))
        txtSection.Text = (dr("section"))
        richtxtAddress.Text = (dr("address"))
        txtBirthday.Text = (dr("birthday"))
        txtName.Text = last + ", " + first + " " + mid

        Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("picture"), Byte())

        If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
            Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
            End Using
        End If
    End While

    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    comm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why you use LIKE on your query? Which size has your image?

Comment: i import my "user_id" from my selected Listview.. 

hmm.? sorry but what do you mean which size?

Comment: Does the error occur anywhere in particular, e.g. the middle of your screen or some specific line of code? Does it occur while loading the first image or after loading several thousand?

Comment: it appears in the middle of my screen

it says OUTofMemoryExeption was unhandled

Comment: The `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using it in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it to use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I change my save routine into this..

```
        Dim filesize As UInt32
        If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please upload some photo to continue", MsgBoxStyle.Information,      "Attention")
    Else
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
        filesize = mstream.Length
        mstream.Close()

        Try
            con.Open()
            comm.CommandText = "insert into Users(user_id, userNo_id, username, password, last_name, middle_name, first_name, course, section, position, address, birthday,picture) values (@field1,@field2,@field3,@field4,@field5, @field6, @field7,@field8, @field9, @field10, @field11,@field12, @photo)"
            comm.Connection = con
            Dim Password As String = String.Empty
            Dim birthday As String
            birthday = cmbMonth.Text + " " + cmbDay.Text + ", " + txtYear.Text
            Password = Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim())

            With comm
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtUserID.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", txtUserNo_id.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field3", txtUsername.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field4", Password)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field5", txtLastName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field6", txtMiddleName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field7", txtFirstName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field8", txtCourse.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field9", txtSection.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field10", cmbPosition.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field11", txtAddress.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field12", birthday)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", arrImage)
            End With
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comm.Dispose()
            MsgBox("Records Successfully Saved")
            clear()
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a try... this is for your get...

CHANGE THIS...

```
   Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("picture"), Byte())
    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        End Using
    End If
```

TO THIS...

```
 Dim bImg() As Byte = dr("picture")
 If Not IsNothing(bImg) Then
    Using pStrm As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bImg)
     PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(pStrm)
    End Using
 End If
```

CHANGE YOUR SAVE ROUTINE...

```
 Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click

 comm.CommandText = "insert into Users(user_id, userNo_id, username, password, last_name, middle_name, first_name, course, section, position, address, birthday,picture) values (@field1,@field2,@field3,@field4,@field5, @field6, @field7,@field8, @field9, @field10, @field11,@field12, @photo)"
 comm.Connection = con

 Dim Password As String = String.Empty
 Dim birthday As String
 Dim ms As New MemoryStream

 PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
 Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(ms.Length - 1) {}
 ms.Position = 0 
 ms.Read(data,0,data.Length)

 birthday = cmbMonth.Text + " " + cmbDay.Text + ", " + txtYear.Text

 con.Open()
 Password = Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim())
 With comm
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtUserID.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", txtUserNo_id.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field3", txtUsername.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field4", Password)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field5", txtLastName.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field6", txtMiddleName.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field7", txtFirstName.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field8", txtCourse.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field9", txtSection.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field10", cmbPosition.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field11", txtAddress.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field12", birthday)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", data)
End With

comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
comm.Dispose()

MsgBox("Records Successfully Saved")
clear()
con.Close()
```

Cheers!
Mr Codexer

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the variable "bImg", when the breakpoint hits, press F10 once and then hover over "bImg" to make sure its not empty and such. If its not then you should be good.

Comment: Also this is the same question you asked earlier, please refrain from doing that...

Comment: oh im sorry.. i think my question earlier is somewhat vague.. so i started to post another question.. 

I changed the codes. but it still getting an Out of Memory error

Comment: Ok, then it's your save. Also did you set a breakpoint to SEE what you are returning.

Comment: i appliead the codes the you have given to me.. but there is a blue underline on this line of codes

Picturebox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
data = New Byte(ms.Length)

it says(Name "ImageFormat" is not declared)
and the other one is Type "Byte" has no constructors

Comment: Be sure that you import the correct namespace: Imports System.IO; in order to use memorystream you need to include this namespace. Also you must include these two imports as well for the image... Imports System.Drawing AND Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Comment: i added the required namespaces but still im getting an error " it still says that Type "Byte" has no constructors..

Comment: I ran my test, I can successfully save and retrieve provided the code that I have given you. Let me know if I can be more of assistance.

Comment: Also keep in mind what marc_s mentioned about varbinary(max), if you get time I would look into this.

Comment: Yeah i change my store image procedure and i can store data.. but still im getting an OUt of Memory error whenever i try to view my Images..

Comment: I was able to retrieve my images.. But i used a different codes.. But thanks for your time.. 

i Really appreciate your help.. Thanks a lot..  @MrCoDeXer

Comment: What did you change? By adding what you changed can help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I change it into this..

Sub fillDataFields()
        Dim arrImage As Byte()

```
    con.Open()
    comm.CommandText = "Select last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + middle_name as name,course, section, address, " & _
                   "birthday, picture from Users where user_id like @uid"
    comm.Connection = con
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", "%" & frmUsers.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "%")
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        arrImage = dr.Item("picture")
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
        txtCourse.Text = (dr("course"))
        txtSection.Text = (dr("section"))
        richtxtAddress.Text = (dr("address"))
        txtBirthday.Text = (dr("birthday"))
        txtName.Text = (dr("name"))
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
    End While
    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    comm.Dispose()
End Sub
```